# How does adventuring level affect job efficiency?

Tags: heroville

In [HeroVille](http://herovillegame.com/), I've noticed that my level 5 adventurer is able to gather 2 resources per tick, whereas a level 1 adventurer only gets 1 per tick.

What is the correlation here? How can I predict how many resources per tick I will get, given the level of an adventurer. Does the level affect anything else about gathering or other jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code responsible for this is

```
$scope.incrRes(Math.ceil($scope.heroList[i].level / 4));
```

This means that you get one additional resource per tick every 4 additional levels after level 1, on levels 5, 9, 13, ...

Answer (score 0):

The level of the adventurer effects all jobs in some way, as previously stated the hero level/4 is the effect this has on gathering.

For each level the production time is also reduced on any item. This is

```
Math.floor((($scope.heroList[i].level) * .05)*$scope.potion.prodTime
```

Meaning the time is reduced by 5% per hero level. So a level 20 hero should produce items in 1 game cycle.